# Custom robot filtering in NCrawler

Tags: c#, web-crawler

Which is the correct way to implement a robot filter, extending the interface `IRobot`in Ncrawler?

In the few documentation I have found, says [it is possible](http://ncrawler.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=InMemoryCrawler,%20IsolatedStorageCrawler,%20DbServices,%20what%20is%20that?) but do not says how to do it. Furthermore, I am a newbie in C# so I don't understand some of the code.

Specially the following part found in the examples, where seems easy introduce a new rules class but not a new robot filter:

```
// Register new implementation for ICrawlerRules using our custom class CustomCrawlerRules defined below
NCrawlerModule.Register(builder =>
        builder.Register((c, p) =>
            {
                NCrawlerModule.Setup(); // Return to standard setup
                return new CustomCrawlerRules(p.TypedAs<Crawler>(), c.Resolve<IRobot>(p), p.TypedAs<Uri>(),
                p.TypedAs<ICrawlerHistory>());
            }).
        As<ICrawlerRules>().
        InstancePerDependency());
```

`RobotService` class is "registered" somewhere there, but there is not setted in any place inside `CustomCrawlerRules`. All the code could be found [here](http://ncrawler.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/79962).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try registering your own **CustomRobotService** in the **NCrawlerModule** registry.

The code should look something like that:

```
builder.Register((c, p) => new CustomRobotService(p.TypedAs<Uri>(), c.Resolve<IWebDownloader>())).As<IRobot>().InstancePerDependency();
```

Comment: Thank you that worked!! I added it in the same way as the `CustomCrawler`, really easy but I didn`t see it.

Question: if I would like to write the concrete solution code, where is expected I would insert it?

Comment: The registration of the modules should be done only once, it wires up the interfaces (abstractions) to their implementations. If you don't provide your own implementations, the NCrawler uses default implementations. Usually the dependency injection registrations for the solution are in a bootstrapper of the application that runs only once before any other application code. But some use-cases may be more complicated, for these, I suggest to do some research in how to work with Autofac, since that is the DI container that NCrawler uses.